# Windows 8 Wifi speeds in two different locations

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, wireless-networking

I have a new Windows 8 machine that I have setup at home and the internet speed is fine. Just as fast as my windows 7 machines. I have taken the Windows 8 machine to a different house with different Wifi connection and the Windows 8 machine is frustratingly slow where the Windows 7 is just as fast as it always is.
Why would the windows 8 be fast at one connection and slow at the other when all the windows 7 machines don't make a difference what house they are at?
HP Envy dv6-7204tu Intel Core i7 8GB 1TB 15.6" LED 1366x768 Win8 64bit 1yr HDMI USB3 Webcam WiFiN

Comment: Most likely a driver problem. Also, can you find out the channel (1-14) and the standard used (b, g, n or even ac)?

Comment: Would it be a driver issue if it is fine in one place and not another? How do you find the channel and the standard used?

Comment: https://tools.meraki.com/stumbler#q=

Comment: @MartheenCahyaPaulo any explanation on what the link does?